ghetto lowrider beach cruiser bicycle
I was given this bicycle, and it has a 20 inch back tire and a 29 inch front tire.
Does the difference in size effect how it rides when pedaling?
Would it be more efficient to have a bigger tire on the back as well?

Can you upload a picture? Some bicycles are made for a 20" rear and a bigger front wheel (usually long-tail cargo bikes).

How efficient the cycling is depends on the gearing and if the setup is done right you cycle as efficient with a smaller wheel as with a big wheel and the gearing for that.

Please used [edit] to add a clear and well-lit photo of your bike from the right hand side.
